# QCompleter for QTableWidgetItem to autocompelte

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget has a QTableWidgetItem that contains a code a user will supply. This code is known to the database and is suppose to autosuggest to the user as he types. How do I connect a QCompleter to a QTableWidgetItem. I know how to do it with a QLineEdit, but I have not found an example with a QTableWidgetItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution, though not exactly by using a QTableWidgetItem, basically I placed a QLineEdit in the cell instead and attached the QCompleter to that.

Comment: Hi! I need to do the EXACT same thing. How did you place the QLineEdit in the cell?

Comment: Never mind! I've never saw the addCellWidget function! Thansk!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how far this will get you, but take a look at this

http://docs.huihoo.com/qt/4.4/demos-spreadsheet-main-cpp.html

Search for `completer` in the code.

Comment: That's using a QCompleter by creating your own widget set.